# What is the better CiviCRM Administration theme on Drupal to apply shoreditch extension?

Tags: extension, shoreditch

Can you suggest me the better CiviCRM Administration theme to apply shoreditch extension? For my experience is Adminimal but I'd like your opinion. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found that Shoreditch had the least issues using the Seven Administration theme but I prefer Adminimal for my drupal side. My settings are as follows:

- Administration Theme - Adminimal (also used for editing and creating content)
- CiviCRM Administration Theme - Seven
- CiviCRM Public Theme - Our main theme

Answer (score 1):

Shoreditch uses bootstrap so you might try the Drupal bootstrap theme, or a subtheme that is based on it.